# Como guardar un archivo como txt traducido por textblob en python

Tags: python, pandas

Buenas noches estoy intentando guardar un archivo.txt que previamente su contenido fue traducido con TextBlob mi archivo es el siguiente ejemplo.txt

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import pandas as pd
import textblob
from textblob import TextBlob

file= open('ejemplo.txt')
dataset= file.read()
trad=TextBlob(dataset)
traducido=trad.translate(from_lang='es',to='en')
traducido
```

Este es el resultado el cual quiero guardar como un nuevo archivo txt lo intente guardarlo pero no tuve resultado recien estoy empezando con python y se que debe ser algo basico espero puedan ayudarme.Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más clásica de hacerlo es así:

```
traducido = "soy un texto\n que va a ser guardado"

PATH = '/ruta/en/la/que/queremos/guardar/texto_traducido.txt'
with open(PATH, 'w') as f:
    f.write(traducido)
```

### Explicación

- Con el `with` hacemos que se utilice el `open()` solo dentro del `with` por lo que cuando se acaba, automaticamente se llama a `f.close()`
- Usamos **w** para indicar que queremos escribir en el archivo.
  Por último utilizamos el método `.write(traducido)` que nos `open()` para escribir el archivo.

Answer (score 2):

hola: no estoy seguro pero una forma podría ser:

```
archivo = open("archivo.txt",'w')
for linea in traducido:
    archivo.write(linea)
archivo.close()
```